# iOS SDK Mutual Friends Facebook API v2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using the Facebook iOS SDK v3.16, which uses the Graph API 2.0. My call looks like this:

```
 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"context.fields(mutual_friends)", @"fields",
                        nil
                        ];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", object[@"profile"][@"facebookId"]]
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          cell.text3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mutual Users: %lu", [result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"] count]];
                      }];
```

`object[@"profile"][@"facebookId"]` is a scoped ID for the app.

The expected behavior for this call would be to return the number of mutual friends in between the current user and the requested user. The thing is, though, that the mutual friend count is almost always 0 (for some reason it is 2 in a couple cases, but it should actually be higher).

The weird part is the error object never has anything in it, and the result object is just nil. I'm not quite sure how to proceed since there are no results being returned and yet there should be, but it is not giving me an error.

Comment: Have you tried the exact same request in Graph Explorer?

Comment: Yes and it gave me a 2500 error

Comment: So I was able to get the Graph Explorer api to work, but still getting results that seem odd. If user A is not friends with user B, but has something like 10 mutual friends, shouldn't the mutual_friends total_count field be 10?

Comment: Both A and B need to grant you user_friends before you can use the mutual friends API. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes I did, both A and B HAVE given me user_friends privileges.

Comment: So both user A and B have granted me user_friends privileges by logging into my app, and it is from this login that I am getting their app-scoped facebook id.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421973/how-to-list-the-mutual-friends-in-ios-using-facebooksdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a working code in swift 3.0 
**Note:** Submit for review to facebook for using this service

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: fbTokenID, parameters: ["fields": "context.fields(mutual_friends.limit(8))"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){

                print("//////Mutual friends")
                print(result!)

            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

// you can also limit result of mutual friends by adding "limit"

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and while I'm not working on this anymore, this isn't quite what I was asking. I wanted to get the total count of mutual friends between two people, which I don't think is possible still.

Comment: @BHendricks, I think you can get the count of mutual friends between two people by using above block of code. I'm using this in my project and it's working :)

Comment: `context.fields(mutual_friends.limit(8))` leads me to believe you're only getting max 8 mutual friends, is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3.0

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters:["fields":"user_id,first_name,last_name,name,picture.type(large)"],httpMethod: "GET")
                //["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"])
                .start(completionHandler: { (connection,result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil)
                {
                    print("Friends are: \(result)")
                    let jsonResult = result as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    self.dict = jsonResult["data"] as! [AnyObject]

                    for item in self.dict
                    {
                       // let id = item["id"] as! String
                        let name = item["name"] as! String
                        self.FBNameArray.append(name)
                        print("FBname: \(self.FBNameArray)")
                        let picture = item["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                        let parsePic = picture["data"] as! NSDictionary
                        let url = parsePic["url"] as! String
                        self.FBImageArray.append(url)
                        print("FBimage: \(self.FBImageArray)")
                        self.TblView.reloadData()
                    }

                }

            })
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and while I'm not working on this anymore, this isn't quite what I was asking. I wanted to get the total count of mutual friends between two people, which I don't think is possible still.