# How to list the mutual friends in iOS using Facebooksdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have followed the graph api but i am getting the response as

```
context =     {
    id = dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQ2NxhPU1adsVlI9wHXlABJbFICZC9PYfcDq57EiAdimkf6Um0P7dgco2lU1qdiM98jXp5hXpZCVkjBeN0DHCROSZAjio6JAD7gmkIZCqTxVp6dNwZD;
};
id = 1306652987;
```

}

My code is

```
FBSDKAccessToken *access = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
if (access!=nil)
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"fields": @"context.fields(mutual_friends)",
                             };
    /* make the API call */


    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"1306652987"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        // Handle the result
    }];
}
else
{
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email",@"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         // Process error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Handle cancellations
     }
     else
     {
         ///me/mutualfriends/[OTHER ID]/?fields=name,picture
         NSDictionary *params = @{
                                  @"fields": @"context.fields(mutual_friends)",
                                  };
         /* make the API call */

         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                       initWithGraphPath:@"1306652987"
                                       parameters:params
                                       HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
         [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"result %@",result);
             // Handle the result
         }];
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
             NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
         }
     }
 }];

}
```

But in the graph API explorer i am getting the correct output with mutual friends name and id and total count of mutual friends but i can't get the full response in my code

Comment: In the Graph API Explorer, are you also using your own app? If so, are the results returned as well?

Comment: Yes i am using my own app in the graph api explored and it shows the full results with mutual friends count and details

Comment: OK, and you're using the call on a friends' node, correct, such as '/me/friends' and selecting one id, and then `/{friend_id}?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)`? I don't think so, at least that's not in your code.

Comment: I am just checking by one of my friend's id which is 1306652987.I am using  this id in my FBSDKGraphRequest

Comment: I am getting the mutual friends details in the graph api explorer by using the above friend id

Comment: And one more thing the friend node even not woking it just gives the count of friends not friend details i am really confused

Comment: I would pay special attention to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user.context/mutual_friends. Check the Permissions section. I bet your error is something there, most likely you are expecting to get mutual friends, but they won't show up unless these mutual friends also have your application installed. There's a solution for this, but It's only recommended for server side calls.

Comment: @corvuszero Yeah thanks i got it finally

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  I made the mistake of using the id/user_id instead of the context id.

```
context =     {
    id = dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQ2NxhPU1adsVlI9wHXlABJbFICZC9PYfcDq57EiAdimkf6Um0P7dgco2lU1qdiM98jXp5hXpZCVkjBeN0DHCROSZAjio6JAD7gmkIZCqTxVp6dNwZD;
};
id = 1306652987;
```

So it should be (in Swift)

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQ2NxhPU1adsVlI9wHXlABJbFICZC9PYfcDq57EiAdimkf6Um0P7dgco2lU1qdiM98jXp5hXpZCVkjBeN0DHCROSZAjio6JAD7gmkIZCqTxVp6dNwZD", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            //everything works print the user data
            print(result)
        }  else {
            print(error.description)
        }
    })
```

ALSO! The mutual friends MUST have had logged in the app AND given the App permission for "user_friends".

So your login should look something like this:

```
 let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logOut()
    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
            }

        } else {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not the right one because we have to put user_id to perform any Graph API request not the context_id