# Facebook Mutual Friends API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Using the Facebook Graph API (v2.4), I can't seem to access any information about mutual friends, not even the total count.

Here's my graph query (User ID changed for privacy purposes):
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/123456789?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)

The result I get is:

```html
{
  "context": {
    "id": "dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQBqWf9ZAHMZA1yjZBJZABsMDkDORNsle8wkS8Acci9r4FsOdyRVl1TSGSXAsofmlaWYS05piSZCV9F1QwNNs0L9XpNuGLAaLyMk8Fnaiwyxpm5shUZD"
  },
  "id": "123456789"
}
```

I tried using FB's iOS SDK to make the same query as well, but got the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to sign the request

Answer (score 3):

The `all_mutual_friends`, `mutual_friends`, and `three_degree_mutual_friends` context edges of the [Social Context API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/) were [deprecated on April 4, 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-4-2018) and immediately started returning empty data sets. They have now been fully removed.

Comment: Is there any other way to get it now?

Answer (score 0):

The `{user_id}` must be another user of your app, and the user access token you MUST use is from another user of your app.

Then

```
GET /{user_id}?fields=context{mutual_friends}&access_token={other_users_access_token}
```

should work and give results, if both users gave your app the `user_friends` permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/mutual_friends/

Comment: what would you put in the {mutual_friends} field?

Comment: Nothing. It's the Field API syntax

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421973/how-to-list-the-mutual-friends-in-ios-using-facebooksdk

Answer (score 0):

```
function aa_mutl_frnd(x, row)
{ 
  FB.init({
    appId      : '<?php echo get_option('_fb_apps_id');?>', //Facebook apps id     using theme option
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
  });  
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            console.log(':acc_tk:'+accessToken);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var data={
                'action': 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt',
                'ddt'   :  accessToken
            }

            $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (response) {
            console.log(':acc_tk2:'+response);


        FB.api(
                "/"+x+"",
                {
                    "fields": "context.fields(all_mutual_friends)",
                    //"access_token": '',
                    "appsecret_proof": response,
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);     
                }
        );

        });
////////////////////////////////////
        }
  });

}
/// ajax part /////
add_action('wp_ajax_wq_accss_tkn_gnrt', 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wq_accss_tkn_gnrt', 'wq_accss_tkn_gnrt');    
        function wq_accss_tkn_gnrt() {
        echo hash_hmac('sha256',$_POST['ddt'],'app_secret');;
        die();
    }
```

Comment: please add some description to explain answer for benefit of others